# C++/Win32: Keyboard input to a non-foreground window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

**My goal:**

I want my application to be able to respond to specific keyboard shortcuts/hotkeys regardless of whether it is the foreground window *without* interfering with other applications' use of these shortcuts.

For instance, if another process has the foreground window and the user presses the `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` key, I want my application *and* the current foreground window to respond.

This function is a user setting, so I'm not concerned about undesired behavior.

**Things I've tried that haven't worked:**

1. `WM_KEYDOWN` messages are only sent to the current foreground window, so my application does not receive them.
2. `GetKeyState()`, according to [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate#remarks), returns the status of the key according to the most recently retrieved `WM_KEY*` messages, and because my application doesn't receive `WM_KEYDOWN` as background window, this status doesn't change.
3. `GetAsyncKeyState()`, according to [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#return-value), returns zero when:

> The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.

I'm not sure what the second half of this means, but `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns zero when my window is not the foreground window.

4. `GetKeyboardState()`, like `GetKeyState()`, only changes key status as messages are retrieved.
5. `RegisterHotKey()`/`UnregisterHotKey()`: Unlike the other options, my application is able to respond to hotkeys even when it's not the foreground window; however, the current foreground window no longer responds. It appears that these hotkeys are redirected to only my application, and other applications no longer see them at all.

**My only (messy) idea:**

The only approaches I can think of are ones that I'm fairly certain would have me shunned by the Win32 community.

I could use `RegisterHotKey()`/`UnregisterHotKey()` to be notified of the hotkey, and then emulate the keypress to the current foreground window. Seeing as `SendInput()` would likely enter a loop, I would need to either unregister the hotkey first:

```
case WM_HOTKEY:
     UnregisterHotKey(...);        // unregister the hotkey to avoid looping
     SendInput(...);               // send keyboard input
     RegisterHotKey(...);          // restore it
```

or emulate it directly with `SendMessage()`:

```
case WM_HOTKEY:
     SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_KEYDOWN, ...);
     // send WM_KEYUP ?
```

Both of these seem like a hack that the Win32 architecture was not designed for.

**Is there any (other) way to read/receive keyboard input from a non-foreground window without interfering with other applications?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` parameter:

Here is a sample:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
HHOOK _k_hook;
LRESULT __stdcall k_Callback1(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    //a key was pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (key->vkCode)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            puts("ESC pressed");
            break;
        case 'A':
            puts("A pressed");
            break;
        case VK_RETURN:
            puts("RETURN pressed");
            break;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


int main()
{
    _k_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, k_Callback1, NULL, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    if (_k_hook)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_k_hook);
    return TRUE;
}
```

It works as follows:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Is there also a way to check the state of the control and shift keys in this callback? If not, I can get away without it.

Comment: @TheTrueJard Try to use `VK_LCONTROL`, `VK_RCONTROL`,`VK_LSHIFT` and `VK_RSHIFT`

Comment: That works, I was able to monitor them via static bools that are updated when those key codes are received. Thanks!

Comment: Better use ```RegisterRawInputDevices``` and check WM_INPUT message in WindowProc